# springframework.context does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning spring, I do my firzt steps.
I have a learning project.
When I opened a project, it writes:
java: package org.springframework.context does not exist

My project - https://github.com/anatoliy19/2.1.4.git

What should I add to my project?

My pom.xml

4.0.0

```
<groupId>ru.javamentor</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-types-of-wiring</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatestplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-4-12_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to execute

`mvn clean install`

command in your terminal?
Also, sometimes dependencies of maven get corrupted, so it is required to remove the content of your .m2 folder

`c:\users\username\.m2`

and after that do the

`mvn clean install` from your terminal

Comment: thanks, I did id.
And now I have just:   java: cannot access org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader
  class file for org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader not found

Comment: thanks, problem has gone.
Now just main class of application is not found. I will ask another question.